# Cakephp - Dynamicly save multiple jqplot images

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, jqplot

I need to render and save multiple charts as images in a single function.

I already created the function to render the image. Also using javascript and ajax I made a functions to convert the graph to image and save it on the server (also adding watermark and text). But this works for 1 chart that you are viewing at the moment. What if I would like to save many charts in a single view?

Comment: You might want to add some more details to your question. Showing code examples is always best. It'll help get more eyeballs on it and hopefully someone will provide you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the JQPLot chart is rendered on the client, The only option you have is to generate each chart, perhaps in a hidden div, convert it into a PNG file which you can later send to the server.

Or you can generate png's at runtime using js and keep on adding them to probably a comma separated hidden variable.